# jquery calculation on the values of rows in table

Tags: jquery

this is my code on jsfiddle

[Visit](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Pn8/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
 //handler to trigger sum event
 $("#targetPrice1").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;

    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("#targetPrice1").each(function() {
    var targetprice = $("#targetPrice1").val();
    var share = $("#share1").text();
    var cb = $("cb1").text();
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(targetprice) && targetprice.length!=0) {
            sum = parseFloat(targetprice) * share - cb;

        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#rowSum1").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

what i m trying to do is to do the calculation with respect to the values on each row.
( like how it works on row 1 )

but i want to iterate each row. ( the class name down the rows is simply increment . like share1 -> share2 from row1 to row2 )

how do i code to have it works?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it. I've commented it out for you to understand :)

http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/C4Pn8/3/

```
$(".targetPrice").each(function () { // Loop through all items will class of targetPrice
   $(this).keyup(function () {
      calculateSum($(this)); // Send the input through to the function
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any complex looping, just do this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.targetPrice').keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var targetPrice = $(this).val();
        var share = parseInt( $(this).closest('tr').find('.share').text() );
        var cb = parseInt( $(this).closest('tr').find('.cb').text() );
        if (!isNaN(targetPrice) && targetPrice.length != 0) {
          sum = parseFloat(targetPrice) * share - cb;
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".rowSum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4Pn8/4/

Note that I gave each row's cells the same classes so that you do not have to worry about id's - so your markup will need to be fixed in order to do it this way.